# debug and run give different output python

Tags: python, debugging

This program counts the number of overlapping occurrences of a string within a larger string.

Input:

- larger string (var name: search_space)<<
  abababa
- smaller string (var name: search_string)<<
  aba

Answer using 'Debug Code' in Pycharm 2016.3: `3`

Answer using 'Run Code' in Pycharm 2016.3: `7`

Expected answer: `3`

My code:

```
import sys

def count_substring(search_space, search_string):
    search_space = search_space.lower()
    search_string = search_string.lower()

    if search_space:
        search_space = search_space.split('\n')[0]
    if search_string:
        search_string = search_string.split('\n')[0]
    lower = 0
    upper = len(search_string)
    curr = ' '
    count = 0
    for curr in search_space:
        selected = search_space[lower:upper]
        if search_string == selected:
            count += 1
        lower += 1
        upper += 1
        if upper > len(search_space):
            break
    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = sys.stdin.read()
    t = sys.stdin.read()
    occurance_count = count_substring(s, t)
    sys.stdout.write(str(occurance_count))
```

The code was modified to help elucidate the error:

```
for idx, curr in enumerate(search_space):
    print(idx, curr)
    print(count)
    selected = search_space[lower:upper]
```

Output Using 'Debug Code': (working as intended)

```
>? abababa <ENTER>
>? aba <ENTER>
0 a
0
1 b
1
2 a
1
3 b
2
4 a
2
3
```

Output using 'Run Code':

```
abababa
aba
^D  
0 a
0
1 b
1
2 a
2
3 b
3
4 a
4
5 b
5
6 a
6
7
```

Note:
^D i.e. Ctrl+D, is pressed because pressing ENTER during Run inserts a newline. Ctrl+D is the only way I manage to get the remaining code to run. But even without CTRL+D the discrepancy remains when a remote test of the code is done (It's part of a self guided non-certificate course)

Note: I have to use standard input and output for this exercise.

It seems to me using `for curr in search_space:` is making the loop iterate throughout the length of search_space and hence more times than it should.

Why doesn't the Break command work?

My questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. & Which concept do I read up more on to understand and foresee such events?
3. Why the discrepancy in Debug and Run modes?
4. How can I foresee and prevent this error in future code?
5. Is there a better way of running this than Ctrl+D ? This crude trick doesn't work in Terminal or IDLE.

Comment: You read twice from stdin: `sys.stdin.read()`.  This method reads from that stream until its end (not the end of the line as in your "run" example). It should only be called once, and you should not touch stdin afterwards.

Comment: Thank you Elmar!  
I realized something was wrong because len(search_string) was zero.  

Would readline() be better here?  
If I do use read() how do I distribute the input between s and t?

Comment: yes, either use `readline()` or split the input into lines afterwards with `split("\n")`

Comment: Elmer you answered in a comment, I can't accept your contribution. If you repost it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code reads twice from `stdin`: `sys.stdin.read()`. This method reads from that stream until its end (not the end of the line as in the "run" example).  It should only be called once, and you should not touch `stdin` afterwards.

If you want to read the input line by line instead, use `sys.stdin.readline()`.

Answer (score 0):

Elmar Peise commented:
You read twice from stdin: sys.stdin.read(). This method reads from that stream until its end (not the end of the line as in your "run" example). It should only be called once, and you should not touch stdin afterwards.

Qubit wrote:
I replaced read() with readline() and it all worked out.
If anyone has any more useful nuggets to share please do so and thank you, but my particular predicament is now solved, so marking this as answer.
Thanks Elmar!